# ok design for mongodb - daily data?

Tags: mongodb

So I don't have experience with Mongodb besides a few tutorials. Currently a website is set up using Mongodb for user access and for some other data. Because of this, I'd like to stick with Mongodb even though I think this may be better in a relational database.

This is what I have in mind using references...

```
{name: Name,
 activity: [00001, 00002]}

{id: 00001
 type: run
 daily: {7/16/2018: {accuracy: 0.5, test: true},
         7/17/2018: {accuracy: .75, test: true}}

{id: 00002
 type: walk
 daily: {7/16/2018: {accuracy: 0.25, test: false},
         7/17/2018: {accuracy: .6, true}}
```

Are the two ok for schemas?

There shouldn't be a need to save all daily data but likely at least 1 year's worth.  Would this be problematic to update especially as the daily structure grows?